# Finder shows .dmg is unmounted, Trash refuses to delete it

Tags: macos, finder, mount, dmg

I downloaded a `.dmg` file for an application, and now after installing the app and unmounting the `.dmg` I can't delete the `.dmg` file because Trash says it's "in use". Finder shows no mounted `.dmg`s, yet if I use the `lsof` command in Terminal and filter for the filename it shows that a process called `diskimage` is using it. What do I do?

I should mention that when I initially downloaded the `.dmg` file to Downloads and tried to open it from there, nothing happened. I clicked it several times and got nothing. My browser was writing a bunch of temporary files to Downloads (I was using an extension to download a bunch of files at once, that was the source of that), so I figured that folder was "busy" and moved the `.dmg` file to another folder. Sure enough clicking on it from there finally got it to mount. I'm wondering if all that clicking with nothing happening earlier actually mounted a bunch of disk images that for some reason are hidden. Could that be possible? Also, I ultimately ended up junking the installed application, but I don't see how that could be a factor.

I am using OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting should clear all the processes that are using the file and unmount all potentially mounted disk images. Once rebooted, try deleting it again.